# Is this FrameWork in Java Possible?

Tags: java, performance, architecture, frameworks

I am creating a framework and which runs the thread and call the call back of other handler .. I want to know is this structure make sense, if not what are drawbacks and how to improve it ..

```
class abstract Main {
public abstract void  handle();
}

Class  Sub {
Main m = null;

public Sub (Main m)
{
  this.m = m;
}
public callBack() { m.handle(); }

}

class A extends Main implements Runnable 
{

public Sub obj = null;
public A  () {} 
public void setB(Sub b) { obj = b;} 

public run()
{
 /*do some process than call the callback of Sub */
  b.callback();
 }
 public handle() {  /* main handle */} 

 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  A aobj = new A();
  Sub newb = new Sub(aobj);
  aboj.setB(newb);
  aboj.run();
  }
```

Comment: You have single-threaded application here. You will not start a new thread by invoking `run()` method.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/procthread.html for more info. What you are trying to create is probably already done - see "Executors" paragraph. Do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: The run method of a runnable is not supposed to be called directly but using a Thread or something that runs runnable. Considering this, this code does not seem in the state of the art to me.

Comment: so if i want to make multithread where thread call handler callback what changes i need todo ?

Comment: Aside from a few minor syntax flaws ("class abstract" instead of "abstract class", missing "void"), capitalization issues ("Class" instead of "class", "callback" instead of "callBack") and typos ("aboj" instead of "aobj"), your code will compile and work the way expected. However, just calling Runnable.run() won't create a thread, so all your code will run in a single thread.

Comment: sorry for typo .. its just a mockup to explain my framework. if i want to create thread what i do as A class is already extend Main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to run the handler in a separate thread, replace the call to run() by

```
new Thread(aobj).start();
```

Comment: this runs the thread but i want to run on every X time than what i need to do .. and will it be multithread?

Answer (score 1):

Listening to a job completion makes sense - i.e. a popular library Guava has this implemented with `ListenableFuture` and `MoreExecutors`. You submit your job to an executor, receive a future to which you can add a `Runnable` which will be executed upon task completion.

If you need periodic execution, have a look at `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool()`.